# Problem with game area on the new form factor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

For my studies, I have to create a game on iOS (like a space invaders). Actually, I'm stucked for the game area : I need that the bullet can be pulled from the maximum value of the x position no matter the form factor.
Indeed, my code works perfectly on the old form factor (as iPhone 8). However, on the new form factor (iPhone X, XS..), the planet can disappear of all the screen.

(I'm a beginner about Swift, so I know there is a lot of mistake in my code). But I think that the problem is from the fact that I divide by an int.

First picture : what I want (which works on iPhone 8)
Second one : My problem.

Thanks for you help (and sorry for my bad english, french people ahaha).

translate :

- zone_de_jeu = game_area
- largeur_jouable = width_playable
- marge_largeur = width_margin
- hauteur_jouable = height_playable
- marge_hauteur = height_margin

enter code here

```
 var zone_de_jeu: CGRect
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        let max_ratio_aspect: CGFloat = 16.0 / 9.0
        let largeur_jouable = size.height / max_ratio_aspect
        let marge_largeur = (size.width - largeur_jouable) / 2
        let hauteur_jouable = size.width / max_ratio_aspect
        let marge_hauteur = (size.height - hauteur_jouable) / 2 
        zone_de_jeu = CGRect(x: marge_largeur, y: marge_hauteur, width: largeur_jouable, height: hauteur_jouable)
        super.init(size: size)

let initialisation_mouvement_planete = touch.location(in: self)
            let mouvement_planete = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            let arrive_final_planete_x = initialisation_mouvement_planete.x - mouvement_planete.x

            planete.position.x += arrive_final_planete_x

            if planete.position.x > zone_de_jeu.maxX - planete.size.width / 6.5 {
                planete.position.x = zone_de_jeu.maxX - planete.size.width / 6.5
            }

            if planete.position.x < zone_de_jeu.minX + planete.size.width / 6.5 {
                planete.position.x = zone_de_jeu.minX + planete.size.width / 6.5
            }
```

Should I modify, my divider by something more general ?

Comment: What is `planete` (in programming, not croissant language)? Also, where are you calling your overridden `init` and how do you initialize your planet object?

Comment: Hey Lucas,

Not exactly sure what you are trying to develop here but my guess is that your calculus for the "GameArea" and "GameRatio" are based on fixed values.

The `safeArea` and `UIScreen.main.bounds` will help you place everything correctly.

I don't see your images, did you forget them ?


Aussi, essais de t'habituer à coder en anglais uniquement ;) C'est pas toujours facile mais ça va venir.

Comment: iphone X is not 9:16, so first thing to understand is how do you plan on addressing this issue?  You are going to have to either crop or create a border on the fatter device (in this case, you would design for 18:39 and instill a graphic barrier on your 9:16 devices

Comment: Hi, thanks you every one, I just put a switch with the resolution of each devices. Then I juste adapt the GameScene from the return of the switch :).